# Complete on Array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array `var $test = $(".main-div").find(".some-class img");`

How do I create `if` statement properly with JS [complete](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp) ?

```
if ($test.complete) {}
```

I need to execute a function only when ALL elements (img) in an array `complete == true`.

// above example not working since it is jQuery object, and it is an array

Comment: $tt is not defined

Comment: What do you mean by *ALL img in this array are true*?

Comment: What is `complete`? What do you mean with "img in this array are `complete == true`"?

Comment: complete return true/false, only when all elements (img) return true

Comment: Please show the definition of `complete` or a reference to where it is defined. Elements don't "return true" -- they are not functions. What do you mean?

Comment: You want to check if all images have completed loading?

Comment: no, I want to create if statement with this exact specs @Kokodoko

Comment: You picked an answer that does not do what your question asks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will return `true` if `every` image that matches your selector is fully loaded by the browser:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".main-div .some-class img")].every(i=>i.complete)
```

Used as a condition in an `if`-statement:

```
if ([...document.querySelectorAll(".main-div .some-class img")].every(i=>i.complete)) { 
  // do stuff 
}
```

`[...]` makes the `nodeList` returned by `document.querySelectorAll` an `array` so you can use the array method `every()` on it. It is called Array spread.

You can also do

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".main-div .some-class img")).every(i=>i.complete)
```

or, if you need to support browsers that support `every()` but not `[...]`:

```
Array.prototype.every.call(document.querySelectorAll(".main-div .some-class img"), function(i) { return i.complete })
```

Comment: That part of the question seemed too trivial. Added it by your request.

Comment: Sure, but why would anyone want that?

Comment: [... do this part is necessary, what it does in this exact case? @connexo

Comment: You use completeD, instead of complete. Also elements query are successful but if statement not working @connexo

Comment: Edited. Removed the `d`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to get all *complete* value. Then you can check the return value if that includes any false, if not then all images are loaded and you can execute your code:

```js
var $test = $(".main-div").find(".some-class img");
var status = $test.map(function(i, el){
  return el.complete;
}).get();
if(!status.includes('false'))
  console.log(status)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="some-class">
    <img id="myImg" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="Tree" width="107" height="98">
  </div>
  <div class="some-class">
    <img id="myImg" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.webp" alt="Skating" width="107" height="98">
  </div>
</div>
```